# Why is my repetition condition with grep range not working?

Tags: command-line, grep, scripts

Searched for a solution on SO, Ask and Unix/Linux but I am lost trying to figure out how to write a conditional with a grep range:

Go through:

```
1-20_something
100-200_something
2-100_something
11-333_something
```

code works but only on `1-9_something`:

```
if grep -q '[0-9]-[0-9]_something' "$foobar"; then
    echo "Additional Code"
fi
```

doesn't work:

```
if grep -q '\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}_something' "$foobar"; then
    echo "Additional Code"
fi
```

and this doesn't work:

```
if grep -q '[0-9]{1,3}-[0-9]{1,3}_something' "$foobar"; then
    echo "Additional Code"
fi
```

What is the best way to range through `{1,3}`?

### EDIT:

To help the next person that may run across this I did a lot of searching and after the answers given I was able to result:

- [Grep for range of numbers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120831/grep-for-range-of-numbers)
- [How to match a specific number range with a regex using grep only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21299332/how-to-match-a-specific-number-range-with-a-regex-using-grep-only)
- [Matching a number sequence in grep](https://superuser.com/questions/452095/matching-a-number-sequence-in-grep)

Comment: Ranges in regular expressions usually mean a set of characters specified using a bracket expression, like `[0-9]` or `[f-p]`. `{1,3}` is repetition or duplication, so I changed your title wording.

Comment: that's fine.  Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Curly brackets `{` `}` are treated as literals in BRE (Basic Regular Expression). From `man grep`:

```
   Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions
       In  basic regular expressions the meta-characters ?, +, {, |, (, and ) lose their
       special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions \?, \+, \{, \|, \(, and \).
```

So you need either

```
grep '[0-9]\{1,3\}-[0-9]\{1,3\}_something'
```

or enable Extended Regular Expression mode with the `-E` switch

```
grep -E '[0-9]{1,3}-[0-9]{1,3}_something'
```

Answer (score 2):

Your second attempt should work if you enabled PCRE (Perl-compatible regular expressions) using `-P`:

```
grep -Pq '\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}_something'
```

`\d` is not in BRE or ERE or in the list of [extra backslash expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/The-Backslash-Character-and-Special-Expressions.html#The-Backslash-Character-and-Special-Expressions) that GNU Grep has, but it is a Perl thing.

Your third attempt should work if you enabled [ERE (extended regular expressions)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04):

```
grep -Eq '[0-9]{1,3}-[0-9]{1,3}_something'
```

`<exp>{m,n}` is not a BRE (basic regular expression) construct.